# How to write format expression for 100k separator in SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services, reporting, ssrs-2012, bids

I have searched on google and nothing found about lac ([Indian numbering system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_numbering_system)) separator in SSRS report and I am familiar with thousand separators, I am using visual studio 2012.

for ex: input 1111500000, output like this: 11115,00,000.

I need 1000 separator and 100k separators both in same format expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following should work for you:

In the format box

[image]

use

```
##\,##\,##0;
```

And this will format the number as per your requirements (i.e. `11115,00,000`).